# How can I combine rows with multiple similar columns but a singular different column

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

The dataframe is filled with movies and their genres as well as the actor name. I want to combine all of the duplicate movies with different actor listings into one movie with all of the different actors.

| NumID | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tt0035790 | Action | History | War | 2017 | Walter Huston |
| tt0035790 | Action | History | War | 2017 | Harry Davenport |
| tt0035790 | Action | History | War | 2017 | Dana Andrews |
| tt0066853 | Drama | 2016 | NA | NA | Ivan de Albuquerque |
| tt0066853 | Drama | 2016 | NA | NA | Rubens Correia |

This is the result that I want:

| NumID | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tt0035790 | Action | History | War | 2017 | Walter Huston | Harry Davenport | Dana Andrews |
| tt0066853 | Drama | 2016 | NA | NA | Ivan de Albuquerque | Rubens Correia | NA |

I want to combine it based on the NumID.

If there is no way to do so in R and Rstudio. I am comfortable with writing to CSV and doing the operations in python and pandas but I would greatly prefer a Rstudio solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61742338/14523964):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(NumID) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = "row",
    values_from = "col5",
    names_prefix = "actor"
    )
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(NumID = c("tt0035790", "tt0035790", "tt0035790", 
"tt0066853", "tt0066853"), col1 = c("Action", "Action", "Action", 
"Drama", "Drama"), col2 = c("History", "History", "History", 
"2016", "2016"), col3 = c("War", "War", "War", NA, NA), col4 = c(2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, NA, NA), col5 = c("Walter Huston", "Harry Davenport", 
"Dana Andrews", "Ivan de Albuquerque", "Rubens Correia")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Haha, I mean it's not too much effort if I use `df <- read.delim("clipboard", header = T)` and use `dput(df)`.

Comment: I thought it was an image. I realized it is a markdown hence one is able to copy sorry bout that